# Does $\mathbb{R}$ have any axioms?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, axioms

Does the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers, with its usual ordering, have any axioms, or do all of its properties follow from the construction of real numbers (e.g., Dedekind cuts)?

Some analysis books state the least upper bound property as an axiom. It's not really an axiom since it can be shown after constructing the real numbers. However, there are several other facts which are called axioms in some books, but I am unsure of which are the true axioms. E.g., is the fact that $$a\le b \Rightarrow a+c\le b+c$$ an axiom or not?

Comment: A set of axioms for $\mathbb R$ is presented in the book Calculus by Spivak, for example.

Comment: And Dedekind cuts is one way to construct one [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatic_system#Models) of that [system of axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach). When you show that Dedekind cuts are Dedekind complete you are just showing that that model satisfies the axiom.

Comment: If you are able to derive thee reals with logic using the natural numbers, then the axioms for the natural numbers are sufficient.

Comment: Actually the least-upper bound property is one of the axioms given in Spivak. I believes he characterizes $\mathbb{R}$ as the unique complete ordered field up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how you define the reals. It's perfectly reasonable to define $\Bbb{R}$ as a complete ordered field, in which case you have the field axioms, the linear ordering, and the l.u.b. property all as axioms.

It's also possible to start at the bottom, with the Peano axioms or whatever, get natural numbers, integers, and rationals, and then construct the reals from there. In that case almost nothing about the reals is axiomatic.

Which is the "right" or "real" way? Neither. Sorry.

Comment: In the latter case, don't we have to impose axioms on the natural numbers (Peano axioms) as well as order structure on the rationals? I.e., will the ordering on the reals follow from the construction of the reals using no axioms, or will it follow from the order axiom on the rationals?

Comment: It follows; there is a natural ordering on Dedekind cuts that comes indirectly from the ordering on $\Bbb{Q}$ (it's actually set inclusion, but the cuts themselves are constructed using the ordering). You're right that we do have to introduce that ordering when we define $\Bbb{Q}$ though.